# How to query two differents mysql tables and compare results

Tags: mysql, join, relationship

I have two Mysql queries:

1:

```
select TblC.name, 
SUM(TblC.total) as Sum
from TblC
left join TblCli on TblC.id_cli = TblCli.id 
group by TblCli.name asc
```

The result is

```
 NAME     SUM
 john    1000
 peter    500
 Alicia   300
```

2:

```
select TblCli.name, 
SUM(TblRec.total) as Pay
from TblRec
left join TblCli on TblRec.id_cli = TblCli.id 
group by TblCli.name asc
```

The result is

```
NAME    Pay
john    500
peter   100
```

There are two different tables with no direct relation
I need to join these two queries and get a result like this:

```
NAME      SUM    PAY  Difference
john      1000   500         500
peter     500    100         400
Alicia    300    0           300
```

How can I perform that?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Demo with your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba6264/6

I highly recommend you do joins by `TblCli.id` instead of `TblCli.name`

```
select A.name, sum , IFNULL(pay,0) as pay, (sum - IFNULL(pay,0)) Difference FROM 
  (select TblC.name, 
  SUM(TblC.total) as Sum
  from TblC
  left join TblCli on TblC.id_cli = TblCli.id 
  group by TblCli.name) A
LEFT JOIN 
  (select TblCli.name, 
  SUM(TblRec.total) as Pay
  from TblRec
  left join TblCli on TblRec.id_cli = TblCli.id 
  group by TblCli.name) B
ON A.name = B.name;
```

Comment: Rahul, Your Reply Was Excellent, Works Great. Really Thanks.